# colour chooser in java gui using buttons

Tags: java, user-interface, colors

I'm supposed to create a Java GUI with 255 buttons for each RGB color. I have the buttons done with a for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i <255; i++)
{
    JButton btnG = new JButton();
    btnG.setBackground(new Color(0, 255, 0 ));
    theGreenButton.add(btnG);
    btnG.addActionListener(this);
}
```

but now I'm stuck with getting the shades right. The first buttons should be black and the last one should be bright green, and for now they're all the same color unfortunately. I searched Google and couldn't find anything; any suggestions?

Comment: This doesn't make all RGB colors. `(i, i, i)` will give you grayscale. `(0, i, 0)` will give you shades of green. There are 256^3 colors (=16,777,216)

Comment: There are actually 16^6 = 16M RGB colors (3 pairs of hex numbers). Are you sure you want a button for each?

Comment: seems like @marta's requirement is to create 255 buttons for only variations of green color, not others.

Comment: for red green and blue, and the idea of it then is that when one is clicked the colour and its rgb number will be shown at the bottom on the gui in a separate panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use your i defined in the for loop as Color value in the Button.

```
for (int i = 0; i <255; i++) {
  JButton btnG = new JButton();
  btnG.setBackground(new Color(0, i, 0 ));
}
```

EDIT:
for your additional requirements:

in the actionPerformed Method (depending on Buttons color)

```
int newRed = btnR.getBackground().getRed();
updateRed(newRed);


private void updateRed(int r){
    int g = bottomPanel.getBackground().getGreen();
    int b = bottomPanel.getBackground().getBlue();
    updateColor(r, g, b);
}

private void updateColor(int r, int g, int b){
    bottomPanel.setBackground(new Color(r, g, b));
}
```

now you need to adept the updateRed method to updateBlue and updateGreen and select te correct color according to your Button.

Comment: any idea of how I could add them to an array list to get me the 3  backgound colors added together ?

Comment: Not sure what you want. You want to add which numbers/colors together? Right now you have new Color(0, i, 0) You want to change the two zeroes, too? Then you have to put your for loop inside for loops.

Comment: So a Button with 3 colors?

Comment: basically I have 3 panels, each being different colour and having 255 buttons in it. I have a fourth panel at the bottom which displays colour of the button that was pressed, but its only either green, blue or red, and what it needs to do is to display 3 colours combined.

Comment: What have you tried? Please show me the code. I guess you want something like buttonAtBottom.setBackground(pressedButton.getBackground()) ?

Comment: this is all the code that i have : http://pastebin.com/UezZkZiz  , and i was trying to work on action performed down at the bottom of the code

Comment: I removed the last lines, your actionPerformed method. and removed implements ApplicationListener. The Code worked for me! (Showed the correct color for the button you click.

Comment: yup it works, but if i clicked a red shade and a blue shade and a green shade I wanted them all to combine together, not just show the shade of the last one clicked :(

Answer (score 0):

You can write btnG.setBackground(new Color(0, i, 0 )); in your loop